# Angular js - Prompt the user about unsave changes before Logout

Tags: angularjs

I am listening to `$locationChangeStart` in my controller. And what I am doing to check if there are some unsaved changes in the view and prompt the user with the dialog either `save` or `discard` changes. It works great. But at the same time, on the navbar I have a button for Logout on which I bound a click event within `navbar` controller. And it looks like this

```
function logout() {
    authService.logout();
    $location.path('/login');
}
```

The above `authService.logout` function ssimply clear all the information saved in a local storage (access token etc). Then I navigate the user to login view, but before it navigate `$locationChangeStart` will raise inside controller that has some unsaved changes. So, when I click on Save changes on the prompted dialog, it throws `authorization` error which makes sense because all the authorization header get's clear as soon as I click the `Logout` button.

I get stuck into a situation, how to handle both things together. Any suggestion?

Note: There will be only 2 or 3 views where I need to prompt the user about the unsaved changes.. In other cases, it works good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need redirect to login view and after that use function logout().

In route config:

```
$routeProvider.when('/login?action', {templateUrl: 'login.html', controller: loginController});
```

At login controller read routeParams:

```
if ($routeParams.action && $routeParams.action === 'logout') {
    logout();
}
```

If you redirect to /login?action=logout you will see "save or discard" dialog and then log off.

Comment: Seems to be a simple and great solution. Still have one catch, when I listen the `$locationChangeStart` event, it has parameter `next` which has a url `http://localhost/login?action=logout`, which I pass into my function that returns me the `path (/login?action=logout)`  instead of `absolute url`. Now, If pass it the `$location.path('/login?action=logout)`, it navigate me to the default `route` which is `/`. Any suggestion?

Comment: It works good when href set with the path /login?action=logout. But not work with $location.path. Also, If my url /login?action=logout, and I am trying to login again, it will then keep the query string parameter in my next route. How to handle this properly